# Working with android animations

Tags: android, xml, animation

i have an android project which i want to create an startup animation to its main activity, i have a photo like a book's first page photo, and i want to my program opens like a book, i know i must use scale animation but i don't know use scale in animations, i have created some scale animations but when it starts the photo just wait for the duration time and finish, its my code which i changed it some times but it didn't worked for me

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:toYScale="0.0"
    android:pivotX="0%"
    android:pivotY="0%"
    android:duration="2000"
    />
```

and thanks for helping me, i just want the `xml` file which includes opening page animation.

Comment: follow this link it can help you https://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/

Comment: you want to do scale animation?

Comment: i am not sure because i dont know how to create this animation. is that scale or transform or what?.